# What does the 's' parameter in the URL mean?

Tags: query, querystring

I am still fairly new to Magento's URL system.

I do know that name value pairs are separated with slashes (though you can also pass a ? and then a=5&b=6&z=etc)

What is the "s" meaning in the following URL?

```
http://www.mycompany.com/smi1304/catalog/category/view/s/grad-packs/id/312906/
```

Does that mean `s=grad-packs` or is s just a delimiter to indicate the start of query parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as `s=grad-packs`.

Your URL can be translated into: `http://www.mycompany.com/smi1304/catalog/category/view/?s=grad-packs&id=312906`.

smi1304 = your store view (i assume)

catalog = module

category = controller

view = action

All the rest are a key/value couple sequence.

Comment: thanks, that confirms I need to figure out what `s` is used for in this case.  I thought it might be a magento specific variable